# DIY: what material to use as DIY shim seat post?

Tags: saddle, seatpost, diy

Seat tube shim adapters are quite expensive, what kind of material do you recommend as a shim?

I have seen in a [thread](http://www.bicycles.net.au/forums/viewtopic.php?f=34&t=40209) some guys talking about home made shim:

- paper tape
- alloy drink can as a shim (aluminium or steel?)
- Thin and quality paper/cardboard

Which one would be the best?

Comment: I would go with the pop/beer can.  Among other things, the thickness of the metal varies with the height along the side of the can, so you can customize the thickness.  And paper/cardboard will compress too easily and make a lousy shim.

Comment: @DanielRHicks Would you choose steel or aluminium can? Some says that aluminium won't slide that easily, but have no idea why.

Comment: Aluminum is easier to work with and "conforms", making it a better shim in most case.  Steel will take wear a bit better in cases where the fit is poor.  Aluminum will "stick" to steel in a way, which is probably good, to keep it from sliding around when you want it to stay put.

Comment: When you get the shim in place, make sure there's at least 1/4" or so showing above the top of the tube, then use a thin screwdriver to bend the top of the shim outward, to make a "lip" that will help keep it from falling into the tube.

Comment: Why shim, if you can buy the right sized seat post?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Soda cans do the trick, cf this [tuto](http://www.instructables.com/id/Seat-post-adaptor-made-with-soda-cans/)

[image]

Comment: That looks like a recipe for a death by a thousand cuts!

Comment: @andy256 - Well, one presumes that he'd put a seat on top of it.  But there's no need for the "ears" to be that long -- 1/4 inch is plenty.

Comment: @DanielRHicks, You're right, this was an artistic touch! Quite nice, hey!

Comment: @andy256 at least!

Comment: This is generally the right answer (I think), but I would not use an aluminum shim on a carbon-fiber frame and/or with a carbon-fiber seatpost, because galvanic corrosion can occur between CF and Al.

Comment: @AdamRice do you mean steel and aluminium?  Carbon Fibre is plastic and doesn't have any electrical conductivity, so it won't suffer from galvanic anything.

Comment: No, CF and aluminum. It’s a well-known problem.

Answer (score 3):

Definitely alloy drink can or other thin sheet metal as it is not compressible and is not affected by water, oil or grease.

Answer (score -1):

Try a rubber sheet cut to size and rolled around the seatpost. It won't slip. Just an idea.

Comment: If you have that much slop, you have the wrong-sized seat post.

Comment: Welcome to [bicycles.se] @Sally. Good to see you here. Since each site is different, I recommend that you take our [tour] and read through the [help]. Then you'll understand why I say this should have been a comment. But I think it would be hard to the rubber in position, and the seat would still feel a bit loose. Hope to see another post from you

Answer (score -2):

Done this a few times, including on trailer DIY axle and the standard pop alum held up over a couple years there without issue.  Also on a prior seatpost issue.

- TO THE GUYS WHO SAY BUY THE RIGHT SIZE SEATPOST there are manufacturers (AND OTHER APPLICATIONS) who don't think standards are for them. 
   Example - just bought a folding e-bike with 36mm seat post. It's also literally twice as long.  It spans use from 5'2" TO 6'5" (157-196 cm) (FUNNY!) and (it says) is good to support 395 pounds (180 kg).  Well - there you go.  Now I want a suspender to go with my hard-tail - and the biggest they have is 31.6.  Which means folding or layering that can - which I did before.

However I would also be willing to try thin sheet aluminium/aluminum from the hardware store - and some kinds of plastic sheet used for durability (thick heat pressed packaging keeps it's properties under extremes.)

I also discovered a handy source of stainless in just about that thickness (2mm/79 thou) - hidden inside just about any hanging file folder.  I went to throw out a bunch and said - hey -- these would be like 40 US cents apiece.  And not only that, but I THINK the folder material would be good for most stenciling apps since it's a hard all through and somewhat water resistant.  Where else do you find 20x15 sheets of stencil blanks for free?

So yeah - I think you just cut a bunch and drop them in to make a circle - if it fits. Bend, solder, cut, done!